# Failed to install any R packages in my conda virtual environment

Tags: r, macos, r-package

I got my new computer (Mac Pro M1) lately but I am not quite familiar with the MacOS system...

I enjoy using VSCode so I configured it with R language. I created an virtual environment with commands:

```
conda create -n R python=3.8
conda activate R
conda install -c conda-forge r-base=4.1.2
conda install -c conda-forge r-languageserver
```

and configured everything following [this website](https://blog.csdn.net/Y1575071736/article/details/117780290). Everything goes fine when I run R language except for installing R packages. Here is a screenshot of my problem.

[image: screenshot of my VSCode]

I can only install packages on R.app:

[image: screenshot of R.app]

Can anyone help me? Thanks so much in advance!!!

I really want to get everything ready for coding in R language with VSCode!!! How to solve it? It seems not a problem of permission?

[image: Privacy & Security Settings]

Updated infomation here:

Below are some screenshots showing what are in my R conda environment:
[image: screenshot_1 of Finder]
[image: screenshot_2 of Finder]

Also, the paths of R and Radian are added to settings of VSCode:
[image: r.rpath]
[image: r.rterm]

Comment: I am not sure why you would torture yourself by implementing conda here (full body shudder). Does R work outside of conda? If not in VSC, does it work in terminal? (To launch R in terminal type `r` and press enter.)  Do you have Radian installed? Are the paths to R and Radian established in your settings.json? Is the path to conda in your settings.json?

Comment: @Kat, Thank you for your reply. Maybe it's not a good idea to implement conda env for R (I just followed a blogger). As you can see above(I've updated the question), everything related to R have been installed. I'm not sure if R works outside of conda though radian is in the folder of envs/R/bin. By the way, it works in terminal (I mean installing packages). I have changed my editor for R to RStudio, which seems to be an excellent editor as well.

Comment: I have to say that I use VSC for many languages, but I use RStudio for R. I wouldn't use conda/Anaconda personally. In R, you don't need to use environments unless you want to use things like `tensorflow` or share objects between R and Python in RMarkdown....even then you may be able to do that without an environment. Are you having trouble installing packages in an environment in RStudio? Have you tried that, yet or did you still want help trying to get VSC to work for you?

Comment: @Kat, you're so kind! (I am new to StackOverflow.) Actually I think RStudio works perfect for me! It's amazing to use R Markdown and R Notebook on RStudio! I don't want to trouble myself with VSCode Configuration since RStudio is enough for me. Besides, I guess I can also write Python Script on RStudio if needed. Hope anyone who sees this question will give RStudio a shot!